# Turning off the Kinect IR emitter

Tags: kinect, openni

I'd like to use two XBOX Kinect cameras simultaneously, but their IR signals interfere.

Therefore, I'd like to be able to switch their IR emitters in an alternating fashion. I read that if using the Microsoft SDK, there was a ForceInfraredEmitterOff flag that can be set, but would not work with XBOS Kinects.

Other sources on the web say that the IR emitter stops when you stop the depth buffer stream. However, that does not seem to work.

I'm using the openni2 python bindings provided by PrimeSense. Is there any way I can shut the IR emitters off with that?